# Where do bombers stand in War Thunder as of June 2015?

Tags: war-thunder

Back when I played War Thunder, my only attraction within the game was to large flying fortress bombers.

When I began playing, however, bombers in the game had recently undergone big nerfs, resulting in issues with bomber gameplay:

- bombers had been given very weak armor.
- regardless of leveling crew to maximum levels in all ways, the accuracy of CPU gunners (an important part of a flying fortress since one can't drive and fire 10+ guns at the same time) was obliterated. The nerf had made the CPU gunners fail even at taking down targets flying directly behind the bomber.
- Guns on bombers had been weakened.

But recently, a friend was talking about the game and claimed that all of that had been fixed, and the game is currently well balanced for bombers.

I'd like to ask you experts here, before I re-install the game:

**What is the state of these past weak traits in bombers?** I'm asking mostly about the armor and (most importantly) the CPU gunner aim, but all details on the subject of the flying fortress's current state of balance are welcome.

Comment: Asking for a state of balance isn't really something we can help with; that a really subjective judgement call.  What we CAN do, though, is point out differences in the stat changes that have been made through the patch notes.

Comment: @Frank Well I specified 2 specific statistics that I was curious about, and used "state of bombers" as a wording to describe those stats combined.